# Does AWS has anything similar to Azure Service Bus Relay?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azureservicebus

I have a service running on my on-premises (data center) and would like to expose it through an endpoint on AWS. Azure Provides Service Bus relay service to achieve this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it). Does AWS support anything like it?

Comment: This may be what you are looking for https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-network-connectivity-over-mpls/

Comment: No that may not work, the solution mentioned is for connecting whole datacenter to cloud which is like Azure VPN Gateway (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/vpn-gateway). I'm looking for a finer solution of exposing a single server behind firewall/NAT to public by relaying through cloud endpoint.

Comment: I'm also looking for the service you want in AWS, but find nothing...

Answer (score 1):

There is not a direct equivalent service from AWS. Some of the messaging solutions such as SNS and SQS can help enable a solution that is similar but would require code be written utilizing one of the SDKs or API. For the network and connectivity piece, a fairly common practice is to use SSH forwarding for this purpose.